# Failed to resolve assembly UniversalApiContract

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, mrtk

Since upgrading from HoloToolkit to Mixed Reality Toolkit, I am unable to build for hololens. The error unity throws is:

`` Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Burst.Compiler.IL.AssemblyLoader.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Burst.Bcl.BclApp.LoadAllAssemblyReferences(AssemblyDefinition asmDef, Dictionary2 visited)
   at Burst.Bcl.BclApp.LoadAllAssemblyReferences(AssemblyDefinition asmDef, Dictionary2 visited)
   at Burst.Bcl.BclApp.FindExecuteMethods(List`1 rootAssemblyPaths)
   at Burst.Bcl.BclApp.GetMethodsToCompile()
   at Burst.Bcl.Program.Main(String[] args) ``

The scene itself is mostly empty, containing only the required gameobjects for MRTK (Directional Light, MixedRealityToolkit and MixedRealityPlayspace, which has the Main Camera as child.)

Unity version 2019.2.6, SDK version 10.0.18362.0

Edit: Building a test scene from the MRTK works fine, so it must have something to do with our project.

Edit2: Screenshot of references.
[image]

Comment: What is your Windows 10 build version?

Comment: Version 1803, though I'm expecting an update any moment now to 1903.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the expanded References of the project? Also, could you file this as an issue to MRTK GitHub? They may be faster to find a solution or understand what's wrong

Comment: Added a screenshot of all references.

Comment: Where does it throw this error? In Unity or in the Visual Studio project?

Comment: It's thrown when trying to build in Unity.

Comment: I upgraded a simple holotoolkit project to MRTKv2 to reproduce your issue, but it failed(Unity 2019.2.8f1,SDK 10.0.18362.0). 
Can you provide a minimum Unity sample that can reproduce this issue?
Besides, according to your error message  it seems like the most possible reason is on Unity side
 and you could try this workaround: copying C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\8.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd  to Unity project.